# Appending an item from a list not working?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

So basically, I am coding a game. On the screen, three rects are displayed (with a picture) as a life. When the ball hits the testrect, it should append ONE life, but it removes all of them?

The code makes sense to me, and works for another part to my game, but when I add this code in, it appends/removes all the rects.

```
#----- the arrays
lives_displayed = []

lives_displayed_array = [
"L L L",
]

# making the rects in the array
for row in lives_displayed_array: #lives/paddle
    for col in row:
        if col == "L":
            lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x, lives_displayed_y, lives_displayed_w, lives_displayed_h)
            lives_displayed.append(lives_displayed_rect)
        lives_displayed_x += 41
    lives_displayed_y += 12
    lives_displayed_x = 5

    #collision with bottom screen/testrect - life removed
    lives_displayed_kept = []
    for life in lives_displayed:
        if testrect.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            lives_displayed_kept.append(life)
    lives_displayed = lives_displayed_kept
```

^^ up on that last bit, it should, `lives_displayed_kept.append(life)` ONE LIFE at a time..

heres full coding since it's hard to visualize i guess

```
#December 16, 2019
#Final Project - Breakout

#IMPORTING LIBRARIES-----
import pygame
import sys
import time

#INITIALIZING SCREEN SIZE-----
pygame.init()
screen_size = (597, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("BREAKOUT")

#retrieve screen measurements
screen_w = screen.get_width()
screen_h = screen.get_height()

#retrieve position of center of screen
center_x = int(screen_w/2)
center_y = int(screen_h/2)

#COLOURS-----
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
PURPLE = (154, 136, 180)

#BACKGROUND-----
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.update()


#PICTURES-----
background_image = pygame.image.load("space_background.png")
easy_block_image = pygame.image.load("easy_block.png")
medium_block_image = pygame.image.load("medium_block.png")
hard_block_image = pygame.image.load("hard_block.png")
metal_block_image = pygame.image.load("metal_block.png")
paddle_image = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
ball_image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
#title_image = pygame.image.load("S4.png")
#block/paddle/ball pictures were created on pixilart.com by myself
#background - https://www.wallpaperflare.com/dragon-flying-above-sky-artwork-wallpaper-181535
#title made from fontmeme.com

#SPEED-----
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60 #set frames per second
speed = [4,4]
paddle_speed = 6

#VARIABLES-----

#paddle
paddle_x = center_x
paddle_y = 600
paddle_w = 78
paddle_h = 10

paddle_dx = 0
paddle_dy = 0

#ball
ball_x = center_x
ball_y = center_y
ball_w = 12
ball_h = 12

#blocks
block_x = 5
block_w = 40
block_h = 10

#severity block positions
easy_block_y = 172
medium_block_y = 148
hard_block_y = 124
metal_block_y = 100

#severity block hits
easy_block_hits = 0

#lives displayed
lives_displayed_h = 10
lives_displayed_x = 4
lives_displayed_y = screen_h - (lives_displayed_h + 5)
lives_displayed_w = 79

#title
title_x = 5
title_y = 5
title_w = 240
title_h = 50

#test rect
rx = 0
ry = 700
rw = 700
rh = 1

#RECTS-----
paddle = pygame.Rect(paddle_x, paddle_y, paddle_w, paddle_h)
ball = pygame.Rect(ball_x, ball_y, ball_w, ball_h)
title = pygame.Rect(title_x, title_y, title_w, title_h)
lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x,lives_displayed_y,lives_displayed_w,lives_displayed_h)
testrect = pygame.Rect(rx, ry, rw, rh)


#FUNCTIONS-----

#https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygameblitopacity
def blit_alpha(target, source, location, opacity):
        x = location[0]
        y = location[1]
        temp = pygame.Surface((source.get_width(), source.get_height())).convert()
        temp.blit(target, (-x, -y))
        temp.blit(source, (0, 0))
        temp.set_alpha(opacity)        
        target.blit(temp, location)

#ARRAYS-----

#empty array to store rects for each block row of level
easy_blocks = []
medium_blocks = []
hard_blocks = []
metal_blocks = []
lives_displayed = []

#layout of blocks for each level
easy_block_array = [
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
]

medium_block_array = [
"P P P P P P P P P P P P P P",
"P P P P P P P P P P P P P P",
]

hard_block_array = [
"I I I I I I I I I I I I I I",
"I I I I I I I I I I I I I I",
]

metal_block_array = [
"G G G G G G G G G G G G G G",
"G G G G G G G G G G G G G G",
]

lives_displayed_array = [
"L L L",
]

#read the array and create the appropriate Rects FOR EACH LEVEL, store them in the walls array
for row in easy_block_array: #easy/blue
    for col in row:
        if col == "B":
            easy_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, easy_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            easy_blocks.append(easy_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    easy_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in medium_block_array: #medium/purple
    for col in row:
        if col == "P":
            medium_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, medium_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            medium_blocks.append(medium_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    medium_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in hard_block_array: #hard/pink
    for col in row:
        if col == "I":
            hard_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, hard_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            hard_blocks.append(hard_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    hard_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in metal_block_array: #metal/gray
    for col in row:
        if col == "G":
            metal_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, metal_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            metal_blocks.append(metal_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    metal_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5

for row in lives_displayed_array: #lives/paddle
    for col in row:
        if col == "L":
            lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x, lives_displayed_y, lives_displayed_w, lives_displayed_h)
            lives_displayed.append(lives_displayed_rect)
        lives_displayed_x += 41
    lives_displayed_y += 12
    lives_displayed_x = 5

#LOOPS-----
intro_screen = False
game_screen = False
end_screen = False

#----------INTRO_SCREEN LOOP----------

#----------GAME_SCREEN LOOP----------
game = True
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #moving paddle with keys
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                paddle_dx = -paddle_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                paddle_dx = paddle_speed

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        paddle_dx = 0

    #constrain this loop to the specified FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

    #PADDLE EVENTS-----

    #store old paddle positions
    old_paddle_x = paddle.x
    old_paddle_y = paddle.y

    #moving the paddle rect
    paddle.move_ip(paddle_dx, paddle_dy)

    #check to see if rect has left screen
    if paddle.left < 0 or paddle.right > screen_w:
        paddle.x = old_paddle_x

    #BALL EVENTS-----

    #moving ball
    ball = ball.move(speed)

    #collision bounce left & right
    if ball.left < 0 or ball.right > screen_w:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]

    #collision bounce top & bottom
    if ball.top < 0:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #collision with bottom - life removed
    lives_displayed_kept = []
    for life in lives_displayed:
        if ball.bottom > screen_h:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            lives_displayed_kept.append(life)
    lives_displayed = lives_displayed_kept

    #collision of ball with paddle
    if paddle.colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #BLOCKS EVENTS-----

    #for blue (easy) blocks
    easy_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in easy_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1

        else:
            easy_kept_blocks.append(block)
    easy_blocks = easy_kept_blocks

    #for purple (medium) blocks
    medium_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in medium_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_block_hits += 1
        else:
            medium_kept_blocks.append(block)
    medium_blocks = medium_kept_blocks

    #for pink (hard) blocks
    hard_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in hard_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            hard_kept_blocks.append(block)
    hard_blocks = hard_kept_blocks

    #for gray (metal) blocks
    metal_kept_blocks = []    
    for block in metal_blocks:    
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        else:
            metal_kept_blocks.append(block)
    metal_blocks = metal_kept_blocks

    #DRAWING/CREATING OBJECTS-----

    #removes screen trail
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

    #drawing paddle/ball inside rect
    screen.blit(paddle_image, paddle)
    screen.blit(ball_image, ball)
    #screen.blit(title_image, title)

    #draws a block for each "B"
    for block in easy_blocks:
        screen.blit(easy_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "P"
    for block in medium_blocks:
        screen.blit(medium_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "I"
    for block in hard_blocks:
        screen.blit(hard_block_image, block)

    #draws a block for each "G"
    for block in metal_blocks:
        screen.blit(metal_block_image, block)

    #draws a paddle life for each "L"
    for life in lives_displayed:
        screen.blit(paddle_image, life)

    #----------END_SCREEN LOOP----------

    #updating the screen
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: as for me you have wron indentations. Why do you check collsion in `for`-loop which creates array?

Comment: What actually happens, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: last `for` makes no sense.  You get life from list  but you check collision between `testrect` and `ball` - you should check collision between `life` and `ball`

Answer (score 0):

I will guess

You check collision between `testrect` and `ball`

```
if testrect.colliderect(ball):
```

but you should check collision between `life` and `ball`

```
if life.colliderect(ball):
```

in

```
lives_displayed_kept = []

for life in lives_displayed:
    if life.colliderect(ball):  # testrect.colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
    else:
        lives_displayed_kept.append(life)

lives_displayed = lives_displayed_kept
```

---

**EDIT:** In full code I see you use wrong method to check collision with bottom. You use method similar to checking collision with blocks.

```
#collision with bottom - life removed

lives_displayed_kept = []

for life in lives_displayed:   # <-- you run test 3 times
    if ball.bottom > screen_h: # <-- you check 3 times the same collision
        speed[1] = -speed[1]   # <-- so you skip lifes 3 times and you change speed 3 times
    else:
        lives_displayed_kept.append(life)

lives_displayed = lives_displayed_kept
```

You move lifes to  `_kept` only when there is no collision but for all lifes you check the same collision `ball.bottom > screen_h:` so three times you skip elements (and three times you change speed)

You have to check it only once (without `for`-loop) and remove only last element from list

```
#collision with bottom - life removed

if ball.bottom > screen_h:
    speed[1] = -speed[1]
    lives_displayed = lives_displayed[:-1] # remove last element
    #del lives_displayed[-1] # remove last element
    #lives_displayed.pop(-1) # remove last element
```

Comment: But I don't want the ball to collide with the lives displayed. If the ball hits the bottom screen (or goes past screen height) then I want one life removed, like examples: LIFE LIFE LIFE *ball hits bottom* (displayed as such on screen) LIFE LIFE